# Vaadin error "Scope 'vaadin-view' is not active for the current thread"

Tags: spring, scope, vaadin

I'm trying to create Vaadin 7.5.5 app with add-on com.vaadin.vaadin-spring.1.0.0. This is not Spring Boot app, but deploy-able war with Spring context which should bootstrap Vaadin.

The error is:

> Scope 'vaadin-view' is not active for the current thread
>
> nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No active view

Here is full error trace:

```
2015-09-25 21:27:33 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:448 - Creating instance of bean 'vaadinSpringApplication'
2015-09-25 21:27:33 DEBUG InjectionMetadata:72 - Registered injected element on class [com.myapp.vaadin.demo.VaadinSpringApplication]: AutowiredFieldElement for com.vaadin.spring.navigator.SpringViewProvider com.myapp.vaadin.demo.VaadinSpringApplication.viewProvider
2015-09-25 21:27:33 DEBUG InjectionMetadata:72 - Registered injected element on class [com.myapp.vaadin.demo.VaadinSpringApplication]: AutowiredFieldElement for com.myapp.vaadin.demo.DefaultView com.myapp.vaadin.demo.VaadinSpringApplication.defaultView
2015-09-25 21:27:33 DEBUG InjectionMetadata:72 - Registered injected element on class [com.myapp.vaadin.demo.VaadinSpringApplication]: AutowiredFieldElement for com.myapp.vaadin.demo.SpringLoginView com.myapp.vaadin.demo.VaadinSpringApplication.springLoginView
2015-09-25 21:27:33 DEBUG InjectionMetadata:72 - Registered injected element on class [com.myapp.vaadin.demo.VaadinSpringApplication]: AutowiredFieldElement for com.myapp.vaadin.demo.SpringMainView com.myapp.vaadin.demo.VaadinSpringApplication.springMainView
2015-09-25 21:27:33 DEBUG InjectionMetadata:86 - Processing injected element of bean 'vaadinSpringApplication': AutowiredFieldElement for com.vaadin.spring.navigator.SpringViewProvider com.myapp.vaadin.demo.VaadinSpringApplication.viewProvider
2015-09-25 21:27:33 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:250 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'viewProvider'
2015-09-25 21:27:33 DEBUG AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor:490 - Autowiring by type from bean name 'vaadinSpringApplication' to bean named 'viewProvider'
2015-09-25 21:27:33 DEBUG InjectionMetadata:86 - Processing injected element of bean 'vaadinSpringApplication': AutowiredFieldElement for com.myapp.vaadin.demo.DefaultView com.myapp.vaadin.demo.VaadinSpringApplication.defaultView
2015-09-25 21:27:33 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:448 - Creating instance of bean 'viewCache'
2015-09-25 21:27:33 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:250 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'com.vaadin.spring.VaadinConfiguration'
2015-09-25 21:27:33 DEBUG CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor:216 - Found destroy method on class [com.vaadin.spring.internal.DefaultViewCache]: void com.vaadin.spring.internal.DefaultViewCache.destroy()
2015-09-25 21:27:33 DEBUG CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor:288 - Registered destroy method on class [com.vaadin.spring.internal.DefaultViewCache]: org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement@5cd39ffa
2015-09-25 21:27:33 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:484 - Finished creating instance of bean 'viewCache'
Sep 25, 2015 9:27:33 PM com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler doDefault
SEVERE: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'vaadinSpringApplication': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.myapp.vaadin.demo.DefaultView com.myapp.vaadin.demo.VaadinSpringApplication.defaultView; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultView': Scope 'vaadin-view' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No active view
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:344)
    at com.vaadin.spring.internal.BeanStore.create(BeanStore.java:71)
    at com.vaadin.spring.internal.UIScopeImpl$UIBeanStore.create(UIScopeImpl.java:279)
    at com.vaadin.spring.internal.BeanStore.get(BeanStore.java:62)
    at com.vaadin.spring.internal.SessionLockingBeanStore.get(SessionLockingBeanStore.java:46)
    at com.vaadin.spring.internal.UIScopeImpl.get(UIScopeImpl.java:81)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:339)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:219)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:351)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:332)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1057)
    at com.vaadin.spring.server.SpringUIProvider.createInstance(SpringUIProvider.java:172)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.getBrowserDetailsUI(UIInitHandler.java:191)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UIInitHandler.java:74)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1408)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:351)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
```

Here is application main class:

```
@Theme("valo")
@SpringUI
public class VaadinSpringApplication extends UI {

    @Configuration
    @EnableVaadin
    public static class VaadinSpringApplicationConfiguration {}
    
    @Autowired
    SpringViewProvider viewProvider;

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        Navigator navigator = new Navigator(this, this);
        navigator.addProvider(viewProvider);
        navigator.navigateTo(DefaultView.NAME);
    }
}
```

DefaultView.java

```
@SpringComponent
@SpringView(name = DefaultView.NAME)
public class DefaultView extends CustomComponent implements View {

    public static final String NAME = "defaultView";

    @Override
    public void enter(ViewChangeListener.ViewChangeEvent event) {
        VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        layout.setMargin(true);
        Button button = new Button("Click Me");
        setCompositionRoot(layout);
    }
}
```

As you may see from logs, spring beans (viewCache, defaultView, springLoginView, springMainView) has been created. But once I've tried to inject it into main class - got the error "**Scope 'vaadin-view' is not active for the current thread**".

Please advice. Thank you.

Comment: Would you also share your DefaultView implementation?

Comment: @mstahv please see uptades

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your issue. Maybe there is something wrong in your Spring context setup? I made this example:

https://github.com/mstahv/vaadin-spring-noboot

Comment: Mstahv, thank you! It start to work once I've modified DefaultView as following: @SpringView(name = DefaultView.NAME)
public class DefaultView extends VerticalLayout implements View {...}